# Change background-image after hover on submenu item

Tags: html, css

Hello I got question regarding setting a background-image whenever I hover on an element of my submmenu. I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default main-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" tabindex="-1">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="nav navbar-nav" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="menuitem_wrapper" tabindex="-1">
                    <a class="home_button not_active" href="#"></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1">
                        <a href="#">My data</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menuitem_wrapper" tabindex="-1">
                    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1">
                        <a href="#">Submenu1</a>
                        <a href="#">Submenu2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menuitem_wrapper" tabindex="-1">
                    <a class="active" href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1">
                        <a href="#">submenu1</a>
                        <a href="#">submenu2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">FAQ</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <a href="#">Logout</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know this is not the proper way to generate a menu with submenu items but despite this, how could I get my grey home button (which becomes visible after hovering on the home button) to stay visible whenever I hover on the "**my data"** button? Is this possible with pure CSS?

I have a demo here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/13Lea4tk/)

Comment: It might only be me, but it seems that your JSFiddle is not working at all. Any external links missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
.not_active:hover {
    background-image: url(https://jira.transvar.org/secure/attachmentzip/unzip/14790/12882%5B1%5D/Home_Icon_for_IGB_pack/home_icon_grey_128x128_more_space_16x16.pn);
}
```

to this:

```
    .not_active:hover, .menuitem_wrapper:hover .not_active {
        background-image: url(https://jira.transvar.org/secure/attachmentzip/unzip/14790/12882%5B1%5D/Home_Icon_for_IGB_pack/home_icon_grey_128x128_more_space_16x16.pn);
}
```

I just added *.menuitem_wrapper:hover .not_active* to the same rule.

Comment: Thank you! that is exactly what I wanted! :)

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery `mouseover()` and `mouseout()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".dropdown-menu a").mouseover(function(){
         $("a.home_button.not_active").css("background-image", "url('https://jira.transvar.org/secure/attachmentzip/unzip/14790/12882%5B1%5D/Home_Icon_for_IGB_pack/home_icon_grey_128x128_more_space_16x16.png')");
     });


$( ".dropdown-menu a" ).mouseout(function() {
$("a.home_button.not_active").css("background-image", "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Home-icon.svg')");
     });
});
```

Also make changes to CSS

```
.not_active:hover {
    background-image: url(https://jira.transvar.org/secure/attachmentzip/unzip/14790/12882%5B1%5D/Home_Icon_for_IGB_pack/home_icon_grey_128x128_more_space_16x16.png)! important;
}
```

Working Example **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/13Lea4tk/3/)**